# MySQL pivot table using java

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have one table BPFinal and has the following column

```
ID   |  Partners  | Branch | Amount | Date 
1001 |  ABC       | BO1    | 2,000  | 2020/11/30
1001 |  ABC       | BO2    | 1,500  | 2020/11/30
1002 |  XYZ       | BO1    | 4,000  | 2020/11/30
1001 |  ABC       | BO1    | 5,000  | 2020/10/31
```

I  am trying to write sql to create a Pivot Table with Dynamic Headers of Partners. Once date is set, it will only display the available partners and its corresponding data per branch.
Output should be like this:

Date : 2020/11/30

```
Branches | ABC   | XYZ
BO1      | 2,000 | 4,000
BO2      | 1,500 | 0.00
```

Date: 2020/10/31

```
Branches | ABC
BO1      | 5,000
```

Any help in writing the SQL would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hello Ask Warvin why is ABC for B01 2000? Shouldn't it be 5000 + 2000 = 7000??

Comment: those are amount with respected date , which means if I select 2020/11/30, the 5,000 amount will not be included.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code. I fear the answers below are leading up the garden path.

Comment: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=523&m=0 check this article out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL in order to pivot dynamically such as

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @date = '2020-11-30';

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
             CONCAT(
                    'SUM(CASE WHEN Partners = "', Partners,'" THEN Amount ELSE 0 END ) AS'
                    ,Partners
                    )
       )
  INTO @sql
  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT Partners FROM BPFinal WHERE Date = @date ) AS b;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Branch,',@sql,
                   ' FROM BPFinal
                    WHERE Date = "',@date,'"' 
                  ' GROUP BY Branch'); 
                  
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c5e53f73def85a631020830c883ee9a8)</kbd>

Comment: Do you have some query use in MySQL to do some pivot?

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the column names of the table:
Like so:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='db_name' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='table'
    AND COLUMN_NAME IN (SELECT Partners FROM TABLE_NAME);
```

Then you wanna union the names like so:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAMES, `<column>`
FROM table

UNION

SELECT COLUMN_NAMES, `<column>`
FROM table
```

And then you wanna specify the date:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAMES 
FROM table
WHERE DATE = 'DATEVALUE'
```

Don't forget to do the join on the results from each of the queries, it is a little bit complicated, but if you stare at it long enough, you should get it. :)

Comment: partners' name will be set as column dynamically. See the output. thanks